# App not installed manually from sd card of android studio 3.0 run

Tags: android, android-studio, version, android-install-apk

I build a new fresh project on android studio 3.0 and copy APK on sd card, when i install that APK manually it's shows me dialog of 'app not installed' whereas if run and install same app from android studio it get install successfully. I tested the same scenario with lower version of studio but no such problem occurred. What change i have to do in my new project for installation.

Comment: Did you tried with Build APK option or Generate Signed APK ? Because i didn't face any kind of problem -> Am using android studio 3.0 from canary channel.

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/10/31/android-studio-3p0-flag-test-only.html

Comment: no its fresh new generated project on which i tested. Actually i am getting this problem on my other signed project also when i run those project from 3.0 version.

Comment: @CommonsWare no its not working i already tried that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to signed your apk with enabling v1 jar and v2 full apk signature.